# How to implement ICloneable without inviting future object-slicing

Tags: c++, object-slicing, cloneable

My question is about how to implement the classic `ICloneable` interface in such a way that it won't lead to inadvertent object-slicing when a future programmer isn't paying close attention.  Here's an example of the kind of programming error I'd like to detect (preferably at compile-time):

```
#include <stdio.h>

class ICloneable
{
public:
   virtual ICloneable * clone() const = 0;
};

class A : public ICloneable
{
public:
   A() {}
   A(const A & rhs) {}

   virtual ICloneable * clone() const {return new A(*this);}
};

class B : public A
{
public:
   B() {}
   B(const B & rhs) {}

   // Problem, B's programmer forget to add a clone() method here!
};

int main(int, char**)
{
   B b;
   ICloneable * clone = b.clone();  // d'oh!  (clone) points to an A, not a B!
   return 0;
}
```

Is there any way in C++ to convince the compiler to emit an error if `B` (or any further non-abstract subclasses of `B`) doesn't define its own `clone()` method?  Short of that, is there any automatic way to detect this error at run-time?

Comment: Same issue, same requirement, but no solution in mind. I even thought about an additional checking tool (in a custom build step) but the C++ grammar was scaring me too much. ;-) May be, with LLVM, it could be affordable to build such tool but my progress concerning this is still stuck in "having the idea"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a while ago that I faced the very same issue in the very same situation without finding a satisfying solution.

Thinking about this again, I found something which might be a solution (at best):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <typeindex>

class Base { // abstract
  protected:
    Base() = default;
    Base(const Base&) = default;
    Base& operator=(const Base&) = default;
  public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    
    Base* clone() const
    {
      Base *pClone = this->onClone();
      const std::type_info &tiClone = typeid(*pClone);
      const std::type_info &tiThis = typeid(*this);
#if 0 // in production
      assert(std::type_index(tiClone) == type_index(tiThis)
        && "Missing overload of onClone()!");
#else // for demo
      if (std::type_index(tiClone) != std::type_index(tiThis)) {
        std::cout << "ERROR: Missing overload of onClone()!\n"
          << "  in " << tiThis.name() << '\n';
      }
#endif // 0
      return pClone;
    }
    
  protected:
    virtual Base* onClone() const = 0;
};

class Instanceable: public Base {
  public:
    Instanceable() = default;
    Instanceable(const Instanceable&) = default;
    Instanceable& operator=(const Instanceable&) = default;
    virtual ~Instanceable() = default;
    
  protected:
    virtual Base* onClone() const { return new Instanceable(*this); }
};

class Derived: public Instanceable {
  public:
    Derived() = default;
    Derived(const Derived&) = default;
    Derived& operator=(const Derived&) = default;
    virtual ~Derived() = default;
    
  protected:
    virtual Base* onClone() const override { return new Derived(*this); }
};

class WrongDerived: public Derived {
  public:
    WrongDerived() = default;
    WrongDerived(const WrongDerived&) = default;
    WrongDerived& operator=(const WrongDerived&) = default;
    virtual ~WrongDerived() = default;

  // override missing
};

class BadDerived: public Derived {
  public:
    BadDerived() = default;
    BadDerived(const BadDerived&) = default;
    BadDerived& operator=(const BadDerived&) = default;
    virtual ~BadDerived() = default;

  // copy/paste error
  protected:
    virtual Base* onClone() const override { return new Derived(*this); }
};

#define DEBUG(...) std::cout << #__VA_ARGS__ << ";\n"; __VA_ARGS__ 

int main()
{
  DEBUG(Instanceable obj1);
  DEBUG(Base *pObj1Clone = obj1.clone());
  DEBUG(std::cout << "-> " << typeid(*pObj1Clone).name() << "\n\n");
  DEBUG(Derived obj2);
  DEBUG(Base *pObj2Clone = obj2.clone());
  DEBUG(std::cout << "-> " << typeid(*pObj2Clone).name() << "\n\n");
  DEBUG(WrongDerived obj3);
  DEBUG(Base *pObj3Clone = obj3.clone());
  DEBUG(std::cout << "-> " << typeid(*pObj3Clone).name() << "\n\n");
  DEBUG(BadDerived obj4);
  DEBUG(Base *pObj4Clone = obj4.clone());
  DEBUG(std::cout << "-> " << typeid(*pObj4Clone).name() << "\n\n");
}
```

Output:

```
Instanceable obj1;
Base *pObj1Clone = obj1.clone();
std::cout << "-> " << typeid(*pObj1Clone).name() << '\n';
-> 12Instanceable

Derived obj2;
Base *pObj2Clone = obj2.clone();
std::cout << "-> " << typeid(*pObj2Clone).name() << '\n';
-> 7Derived

WrongDerived obj3;
Base *pObj3Clone = obj3.clone();
ERROR: Missing overload of onClone()!
  in 12WrongDerived
std::cout << "-> " << typeid(*pObj3Clone).name() << '\n';
-> 7Derived

BadDerived obj4;
Base *pObj4Clone = obj4.clone();
ERROR: Missing overload of onClone()!
  in 10BadDerived
std::cout << "-> " << typeid(*pObj4Clone).name() << '\n';
-> 7Derived
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dfc44d26e13bb01a)

The trick is actually quite easy:

Instead of overriding `clone()` itself, it is used as trampoline into a `virtual onClone()` method. Hence, `clone()` can check the result for correctness before returning it.

This is not a compile-time check but a run-time check (what I consider as second best option). Assuming that every class of a class library in development should hopefully be checked / debugged at least during development I find this quite reliable.

---

The accepted answer to [SO: Reusable member function in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62932563/7478597) showed me a way to make this even more immune against copy/paste errors:

Instead of typing out the class name in every overridden `clone()`, the class name is obtained via `decltype()`:

```
class Instanceable: public Base {
  public:
    Instanceable() = default;
    Instanceable(const Instanceable&) = default;
    Instanceable& operator=(const Instanceable&) = default;
    virtual ~Instanceable() = default;
    
  protected:
    virtual Base* onClone() const
    {
      return new std::remove_const_t<std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(this)>>(*this);
    }
};

class Derived: public Instanceable {
  public:
    Derived() = default;
    Derived(const Derived&) = default;
    Derived& operator=(const Derived&) = default;
    virtual ~Derived() = default;
    
  protected:
    virtual Base* onClone() const override
    {
      return new std::remove_const_t<std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(this)>>(*this);
    }
};
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db79bdc7223a78f4)

Answer (score 0):

Don't make A and B inherit from IClonable. Use a wrapper (BluePrint) instead :

```cpp
struct IClonable {
    virtual ~IClonable() = default;
    virtual IClonable * clone() const = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class BluePrint final : IClonable {
public:
    explicit BluePrint(T * element) : element(element) {
    }
    IClonable * clone() const override {
        T * copy = element->clone();
        return new BluePrint(copy);
    }
    T * get() const {
        return element;
    }

private:
    T * const element;
};

struct A {
    A * clone() const;
};

struct B : A {
    B * clone() const;
};
```

You will have to tinker on the code a bit though, since this returns a clone of the wrapper and not immediately a clone of the element to be cloned. Then again, I don't know how you are planning to use the IClonable interface, so I can't complete this example for you.

Comment: The problem is, AFAICT the `BluePrint` class can't be used in polymorphic fashion.  i.e. in order to instantiate a `BluePrint<B>` I have to know at compile-time that the underlying object is a `B`; and at that point I might as well skip the `IClonable` interface entirely and just use B's copy-constructor directly.